# In the adjoining figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In the adjoining figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. If $DF=CE$ and $AG||HF$ then prove that $||gm FAGH =||gm ABCD$.

[image]

My Attempt. 
$1. FD=EC$
$2. FD+DE=EC+DE$
$3. FE=DC$.

What should I do further to complete this?

Comment: What is $||gm$?

Comment: Parallelogram....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $CE=DF$, we have
$$[\triangle{BEC}]=[\triangle{AFD}]\tag1$$

Also we get
$$\begin{align}AB&=CD\\&=CE+ED\\&=DF+ED\\&=FE\end{align}$$
so $ABEF$ and $FAGH$ are parallelograms.

Since $HF=GA,FE=AB$ and $\angle{HFE}=\angle{GAB}$, we get
$$\triangle{HFE}\equiv \triangle{GAB}$$
from which we get $$[\triangle{HFE}]=[\triangle{GAB}],$$
i.e.
$$[\square{HGDF}]+[\triangle{GED}]=[\square{DEBA}]+[\triangle{GED}]$$
So, 
$$[\square{HGDF}]=[\square{DEBA}]\tag2$$

The claim follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$.